# Capture windows behind my window using GPU and without changing window affinity

Tags: c++, windows, image-processing, gpu, direct3d

I want to capture all windows except my own window and I need this to be as fast as possible (in terms of FPS). Now, there are couple of similar questions already asked and answered, but none of them really satisfy my requirements.

Setting window affinity is not an option, because I want other apps to be able to capture my window.

I'm unable to find a single API that does this. So, maybe the only option is to capture all windows separately and then somehow merge then into a single image using each window's size, position and Z-index. There are dozens of APIs to capture windows on Windows. At this moment, `Windows.Graphics.Capture` seems to be a good one with `C++` support, but I'm open to consider anything else if it runs on GPU and makes it easier to merge those separate windows.

*Maybe merging/combining could be a separate question, but this way it has more context. However, I'll edit my question if needed.*

Comment: [`DwmRegisterThumbnail`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmregisterthumbnail). the DWM gives you full-resolution "thumbnails" (keyword) of every window. when they aren't minimized, they even update completely. that API will tell DWM to continuously copy some window's bitmap into your own buffer/wnd ("relationships" are work).

Comment: Hi @ChristophRackwitz, thanks for the hint. Seems that using thumbnails drops shadows as part of thumbnail adornment process (not for every window though). Is there a way to get rid of this? If yes, then that's probably an answer to this question. Thanks!

Comment: to me, on windows 10, it looks like all the window chrome is there, just not the shadows. might be clipped off, or not part of the process at all. windows explorer windows have certain hitbox so that includes the dropshadows... -- some remote desktop programs seem to use this API and they seem to draw the shadows separately (if the effect is enabled on that desktop and needs to be replicated).

Comment: Well it seems that some shadows are missing when previewing in the destination window, but when capturing the window using BitBlt (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image?redirectedfrom=MSDN) all shadows are there. If you would like, let's convert this to an answer.